# Проблема с окнами tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Сначала хотелось бы показать непосредственно код:

```
from tkinter import *
#test1 - приятно ли с вами общаться
#test2 - благоразумие
count=0
#класс для вопроса
class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, number, question_text):
        """Constructor"""
        self.number = number
        self.question_text = question_text
    def create_question(self):
        global count
        question_window = Tk()
        question_window.title(f"Вопрос {self.number}")
        question_window.geometry('500x500+100+100')
        question_number = Label(question_window, text=(f"Вопрос номер {self.number}"), font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
        question_number.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
        question_number = Label(question_window, text=(f"{self.question_text}"), font="Arial 10", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
        question_number.place(relx=0, rely=0.4, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
        def answer_yes():
            global count
            count+=1
            question_window.destroy()
        def answer_no():
            question_window.destroy()
        answer_yes = Button(question_window, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=answer_yes)
        answer_no = Button(question_window, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=answer_no)
        answer_yes.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
        answer_no.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
        question_window.mainloop()
#основное окно, должно открываться после каждого прохождения теста, по нажатию кнопки
def main_window():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Психологический тест")
    root.geometry('700x700+100+100')
    choose_lab = Label(root, text="Выберите тест", width=30, height=1, font="Arial 20", background="gray93")
    choose_lab.place(x=100, y=1)
    test2_but = Button(root, text="Приятно ли с Вами общаться?", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test1_fun)
    test2_but.place(x=100, y=180)
    test3_but = Button(root, text="Благоразумны ли Вы?", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test2_fun)
    test3_but.place(x=100, y=380)
    root.mainloop()
#вопросы
test1_question1 = Question(number=1, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question2 = Question(number=2, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question3 = Question(number=3, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question4 = Question(number=4, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question5 = Question(number=5, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question6 = Question(number=6, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question7 = Question(number=7, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question8 = Question(number=8, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question9 = Question(number=9, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question10 = Question(number=10, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test1_question11 = Question(number=11, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question1 = Question(number=1, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question2 = Question(number=2, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question3 = Question(number=3, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question4 = Question(number=4, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question5 = Question(number=5, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question6 = Question(number=6, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question7 = Question(number=7, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question8 = Question(number=8, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question9 = Question(number=9, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question10 = Question(number=10, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
test2_question11 = Question(number=11, question_text="Вы любите больше слушать, чем говорить?")
#функция первого теста, здесь возможные проблемы
def test1_fun():
    global count
    def test1_shutdown():
        test1.destroy()
    def test1_start():
        def test1_end():
            test1_end_window = Tk()
            test1_end_window.title("Тест 2. Результат")
            test1_end_window.geometry('500x500+100+100')
            count_label = Label(test1_end_window, text=(f"Вы набрали {count} баллов"), font="Arial 20",
                                background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
            count_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
            test1_result = Label(test1_end_window, text=(f"1"), font="Arial 10", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
            test1_result.place(relx=0, rely=0.4, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
            test1_exit = Button(test1_end_window, text="Завершить", background="gray90", font="Arial 16",
                                command=main_window)
            test1_exit.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.30, relheight=0.1)
        test1_descr.destroy()
        test1_ready.destroy()
        test1_notready.destroy()
        test1.destroy()
        root.destroy()
        test1_question1.create_question()
        test1_question2.create_question()
        test1_question3.create_question()
        test1_question4.create_question()
        test1_question5.create_question()
        test1_question6.create_question()
        test1_question7.create_question()
        test1_question8.create_question()
        test1_question9.create_question()
        test1_question10.create_question()
        test1_question11.create_question()
        test1_end()
        #print(count)
    test1 = Tk()
    test1.title("Тест 1. Приятно ли с Вами общаться?")
    test1.geometry('500x500+100+100')
    test1_descr = Label(test1, text="Вы готовы пройти тест из 11 вопросов?", font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
    test1_descr.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    test1_ready = Button(test1, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test1_start)
    test1_notready = Button(test1, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test1_shutdown)
    test1_ready.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    test1_notready.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
#функция второго теста, здесь возможные проблемы
def test2_fun():
    global count
    def test2_shutdown():
        test2.destroy()
    def test2_start():
        def test2_end():
            test2_end_window = Tk()
            test2_end_window.title("Тест 2. Результат")
            test2_end_window.geometry('500x500+100+100')
            count_label = Label(test2_end_window, text=(f"Вы набрали {count} баллов"), font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
            count_label.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
            test2_result = Label(test2_end_window, text=(f"1"), font="Arial 10", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
            test2_result.place(relx=0, rely=0.4, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
            test2_exit = Button(test2_end_window, text="Завершить", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=main_window)
            test2_exit.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.30, relheight=0.1)
        test2_descr.destroy()
        test2_ready.destroy()
        test2_notready.destroy()
        root.destroy()
        test2.destroy()
        test2_question1.create_question()
        test2_question2.create_question()
        test2_question3.create_question()
        test2_question4.create_question()
        test2_question5.create_question()
        test2_question6.create_question()
        test2_question7.create_question()
        test2_question8.create_question()
        test2_question9.create_question()
        test2_question10.create_question()
        test2_question11.create_question()
        test2_end()
        #print(count)
    test2 = Tk()
    test2.title("Тест 2. Благоразумны ли вы?")
    test2.geometry('500x500+100+100')
    test2_descr = Label(test2, text="Вы готовы пройти тест из 11 вопросов?", font="Arial 20", background="gray93", justify=CENTER)
    test2_descr.place(relx=0, rely=0.3, relwidth=1, relheight=0.1)
    test2_ready = Button(test2, text="Да", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test2_start)
    test2_notready = Button(test2, text="Нет", background="gray90", font="Arial 16", command=test2_shutdown)
    test2_ready.place(relx=0.73, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
    test2_notready.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.7, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)
#первое основное окно, используется из-за некоторых багов, функции тестов не воспринимают имя root из функции main_window
root = Tk()
root.title("Психологический тест")
root.geometry('700x700+100+100')
choose_lab = Label(root, text="Выберите тест", width=30, height=1, font="Arial 20", background="gray93")
choose_lab.place(x=100, y=1)
test2_but = Button(root, text="Приятно ли с Вами общаться?", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test1_fun)
test2_but.place(x=100, y=180)
test3_but = Button(root, text="Благоразумны ли Вы?", width=30, height=2, font="Arial 20", background="gray90", command=test2_fun)
test3_but.place(x=100, y=380)
root.mainloop()
```

И текст ошибки:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\clash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\clash\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\тест.py", line 130, in test2_start
    root.destroy()
  File "C:\Users\clash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2341, in destroy
    self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

Эта ошибка возникает, когда после прохождения одного теста я хочу начать второй, и наоборот, если прошёл второй и хочу пройти первый. Второй не запускается. Как я понял, `root.destroy()`в функциях `test1_start`  и `test2_start` не работает, т.к. пытается удалить окно, которого уже нет. Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь мог проходить сколько угодно тестов без перезапуска программы. Также наблюдается проблема в том, что экраны окончания `test1_end_window` и `test2_end_window` не закрываются, после нажатия кнопки `test1_exit` и `test2_exit` соответственно. Нужно, чтобы эта кнопка закрывала окно завершения и открывала основное окно `root` с выбором теста. В коде закомментированы некоторые пояснения к нему. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Я не разобрался в чем ошибка, как-то все свалено в кучу. Очень много окрывающихся и закрывающихся окон.

1. Нужно основное окно(root) для выбора теста.
2. Oно открывает окно второго уровня (Toplevel) с 1-м вопросом.
3. При ответе на вопрос, текст в метках Label должен меняться на следущий вопрос.
4. Когда вопросы закончаться выдается результат.
   Чтоб легко изменять метки, в будущем вопросы и проверочные ответы надо их собрать в кортежи.Почитайте сайт https://younglinux.info/tkinter/tkinter. Хотел добавить заготовку программы, но редактор пишет, что она не отформатирована и не пропускает.

Comment: У меня есть вопрос, где я спрашиваю о переходе между вопносами изменением одного Label, ответа толкового не получил, решил сделать так, как сейчас, каждый новый вопрос в новом окне

Comment: И в ещё, я читал этот сайт ещё до начала наеисания программы. И повторюсь, у меня не вышло сделать изменение виджетов одного окна для каждого вопроса. Да и сейчас не представляю, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот скинул заготовку программы на gist https://gist.github.com/SergioKoh/4c60eceb197e999ce2ab3f1ca4977497

Comment: Можете посмотреть мой комментарий под этим кодом? Там один вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спустя полтора месяца xd). Какие блоки кода нужно убрать, чтобы остался только первый тест, второй нужно убрать. Просто если я тупо убираю все части, связанные со вторым тестом(кнопку его выбора, кортеж вопросов, ответы), у меня ломается первый тест, который как раз таки нужен.